# Django: Get one key and value from queryset dictionary

Tags: python, django, printing, django-queryset

I have this query:
`item = Item.objects.filter(id=3)`

It is returning a queryset with its the keys and values.
Now I need to extract a particular value from the queryset, like this:

`item_name = item['name']`

But it does not work. How can I achieve this? Send the most simple way if possible, please. Thanks!

Comment: A sample of the queryset?

Comment: <QuerySet [{'id': 3, 'employee': 'nYY', 'code': 'a_3', 'name': 'John', 'date': None}]>

Comment: `filter()` returns a QuerySet which you need to iterate over. But you will be iterating over your model objects which are not dicts so you can't access them by key but by attribute. `for item in Item.objects.filter(id=3): print(item.name)`.

In this case you are doing what looks like a PK lookup, so you should use `get(id=3)` instead `filter()` and in this case do: `item = Item.objects.get(id=3)` then `item.name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several wrong assumptions here.

A queryset is not a dict and does not have keys and values. It's a sequence of items, if anything most similar to a list.

I *think* what you want to do is to get a specific instance from the database, and access its fields. To get one instance you use `get`, not `filter`, as filter will always give you a queryset even if there is only a single match. Then, from that instance, you use attribute access not dict lookup. So:

```
item = Item.objects.get(id=3)
item_name = item.name
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel. Your answer is correct, but I need to use several attributes of the object that I'm getting (not just one), therefore I think using get so many times will result in several queries, and it will be slower than a single query which I can access to its different attributes from it. Any other way to do this?

Comment: What? You only need to get the item once, then you can reference as many of its attributes as you like.

Comment: Oh it's right, it worked perfectly. I had a wrong concept about get. Thank you again.

Comment: If there are multiple items with same value and we want to get only one related query set, then in the above case 'get'   won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use the getattr function of python through which you can get your objective.

```
getattr(item, 'name')
```